# Nested routes not working in React app deployed to Netlify

Tags: javascript, reactjs, netlify

In my React app deployed at `main--fascinating-melba-bd8f4d.netlify.app`, I’m using `react-router-dom`, but I’m having trouble getting my nested routes to work. The child routes are supposed to only be accessible once the user successfully logs in.

This is the code:

```
<Route path='/private' element={<Auth />}>
  <Route path='/private/my-profile' element={<MyProfile />} />
  <Route path='/private/sell-something' element={<Sell />} />
</Route>
```

The nested routes work fine on my local server. Once users log in, they’re able to view their profile at `localhost:3000/private/my-profile` and the page for selling an item at `localhost:3000/private/sell-something`. But neither of those two child routes can be accessed on my Netlify site, even after a successful login. The React functional components, `<MyProfile />` and `<Sell />`, which are passed to the Route elements, are not even rendered when a logged-in user goes to [this](https://main--fascinating-melba-bd8f4d.netlify.app/private/my-profile) or [that URL](https://main--fascinating-melba-bd8f4d.netlify.app/private/sell-something). And when you’re not logged in, visiting these URLs does not result in your being redirected to the [login page](https://main--fascinating-melba-bd8f4d.netlify.app/login) like it’s supposed to.

I have a `public/_redirects` file with the content `/* /index.html 200`, so the issue is not that I neglected to create that file. All of my routes work fine, except the nested ones.

If it helps, here are the contents of `Auth.js`, from which the Auth element is imported:

```
import { Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useUser } from '../lib/useUser';

export const Auth = () => {
  const user = useUser();

  if (!user) return <Navigate to='/login' />;

  return <Outlet />;
};
```

And the following two files, contained in the `lib` folder, are `useUser.js` and `useToken.js`, respectively:

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useToken } from './useToken';

export const useUser = () => {
  const [token] = useToken();

  const getPayloadFromToken = (token) => {
    const encodedPayload = token.split('.')[1];
    return JSON.parse(atob(encodedPayload));
  };

  const [user, setUser] = useState(() => {
    if (!token) return null;
    return getPayloadFromToken(token);
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!token) setUser(null);
    else setUser(getPayloadFromToken(token));
  }, [token]);

  return user;
};
```

```js
import { useState } from 'react';

export const useToken = () => {
  const [token, setTokenInternal] = useState(() => {
    return localStorage.getItem('token');
  });

  const setToken = (newToken) => {
    localStorage.setItem('token', newToken);
    setTokenInternal(newToken);
  };

  return [token, setToken];
};
```

Comment: How are you building your app, using `react-scripts`, `vite` or something else? Your path to compiled JS assets is incorrect

Comment: I'm using `react-scripts`. Or rather, that's what Netlify uses to build the app for me. What error do you see?

Comment: To elaborate, your `index.html` file is being generated with relative paths to assets, eg `<script src="./static/js/main.c8a01835.js">`. This is failing on any URL path more than 1 level deep. The asset paths should be absolute.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I see what you're saying. Let me try making all those paths absolute and redeploying to Netlify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your index.html file is being generated with relative paths to assets, eg

```html
<script defer src="./static/js/main.c8a01835.js"></script>
```

This is failing on any URL path more than 1 level deep.

You cannot use

```json
"homepage": ".",
```

in your `package.json` if you're using client-side routing.

That should only be used to serve the [same build from different paths](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#serving-the-same-build-from-different-paths), specifically...

> If you are **not** using the HTML5 pushState history API or **not** using client-side routing at all

Simply remove the `"homepage"` line from your `package.json`, redeploy your app and question why you added it in the first place.

This will use the default static asset path of `"/"`.